# Grails - ClassCastException with SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper

Tags: grails, oc4j

I am facing a strange issue in my grails application. It stops rendering the data intermittently after some idle days (if no one use the application) and shows the below html output afterwards:
[image]

However, **it starts working again if I bounce the container or stop/start the application in container**. I am deploying my application into OC4J 10.1.3.5.0.

I can see the following exception in my application log file:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.errors.GrailsWrappedRuntimeException: org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.ErrorHandlingServlet.doDispatch(ErrorHandlingServlet.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:743)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
    at com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.invoke(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:734)
    at com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.forwardInternal(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:391)
    at com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.unprivileged_forward(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:280)
    at com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.access$100(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:68)
    at com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher$2.oc4jRun(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:214)
    at oracle.oc4j.security.OC4JSecurity.doPrivileged(OC4JSecurity.java:284)
    at com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.forward(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:219)
    at com.evermind.server.http.EvermindHttpServletResponse.sendError(EvermindHttpServletResponse.java:1446)
    at com.evermind.server.http.EvermindHttpServletResponse.handleException(EvermindHttpServletResponse.java:1878)
    at com.evermind.server.http.EvermindHttpServletResponse.handleException(EvermindHttpServletResponse.java:1718)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.handleNotFound(HttpRequestHandler.java:1091)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.doProcessRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:948)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.processRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:458)
    at com.evermind.server.http.AJPRequestHandler.run(AJPRequestHandler.java:313)
    at com.evermind.server.http.AJPRequestHandler.run(AJPRequestHandler.java:199)
    at oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketReadHandler$SafeRunnable.run(ServerSocketReadHandler.java:260)
    at com.evermind.util.ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor$MyWorker.run(ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor.java:303)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper
    at com.evermind.server.http.NotFoundServlet.sendNotFound(NotFoundServlet.java:26)
    at com.evermind.server.http.NotFoundServlet.service(NotFoundServlet.java:18)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
    at com.evermind.server.http.ResourceFilterChain.doFilter(ResourceFilterChain.java:64)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter.UrlMappingsFilter.processFilterChain(UrlMappingsFilter.java:287)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter.UrlMappingsFilter.doFilterInternal(UrlMappingsFilter.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at com.evermind.server.http.EvermindFilterChain.doFilter(EvermindFilterChain.java:15)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter.obtainContent(GrailsPageFilter.java:245)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter.doFilter(GrailsPageFilter.java:134)
    at com.evermind.server.http.EvermindFilterChain.doFilter(EvermindFilterChain.java:17)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:366)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java:40)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:167)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at com.evermind.server.http.EvermindFilterChain.doFilter(EvermindFilterChain.java:17)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at com.evermind.server.http.EvermindFilterChain.doFilter(EvermindFilterChain.java:17)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at com.evermind.server.http.EvermindFilterChain.doFilter(EvermindFilterChain.java:17)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.invoke(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:642)
    at com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.forwardInternal(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:391)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.handleNotFound(HttpRequestHandler.java:1087)
    ... 7 more
```

Grails and used plugins version are as follows:

```
app.grails.version=1.3.7
app.servlet.version=2.4

plugins.audit-logging=0.5.4
plugins.calendar=1.2.1
plugins.filterpane=2.0.1.1
plugins.hibernate=1.3.7
plugins.spring-security-core=1.1.2
plugins.spring-security-ldap=1.0.3
plugins.tomcat=1.3.7
plugins.tooltip=0.7
```

Appreciate any help in this regard.

Comment: Grails 1.3.7 is a very old version of Grails. Have you ever tried to upgrade to at least Grails 2.0?

Comment: do you think it is grails 1.3.7 issue??

Comment: Maybe. Have you ever run your 1.3.7 in a Tomcat? If yes do you get the same problems?

Comment: Can you provide more information about that `java.lang.ClassCastException`? What is OC4J trying to cast into what?

Comment: I have provided the full stack trace above... however, i have not faced this issue in tomcat.

Comment: is your container redeploying automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a spring security issue, but you may have to update to newer grails to use the newer spring security code.